# Aggregate values and display in barplot

Tags: r, plot, visualization, bar-chart

I have the following matrix:

```
group,value
a,2
b,4
a,3
a,2
b,5
```

I want to aggregate it by group and visualize it in a barplot:

```
9   --
8    
7 -- 
6   
5   
4   
3   
2   
1   
-------
  a  b
```

With

```
barplot(as.matrix(aggregate(csv[2], csv[1], sum)))
```

I get the following plot:

[image: plot]

So both groups are on only 1 bar. How can display 2 bars (1 for every group)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the group as rownames will produce 2 bars:

```
barplot(t(as.matrix((data.frame(aggregate(csv[2],csv[1],sum),row.names=1)))))
```